# JavaScript read radio button value in IE and FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I have a simple web form that uses JavaScript for building a POST statement. In Chrome, I can use a simple line of code...

```
var form = document.forms['myForm'];
var env = form.env.value;
```

The form itself looks like this...

```
<form name="myForm" action='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("/path/to/some/pythoncode.py")'>
    <input type="radio" name="env" id="env" value="inside">Inside
    <input type="radio" name="env" id="env" value="outside" checked="checked">Outside
    <input type="radio" name="env" id="env" value="both">Both
    <input type="radio" name="env" id="env" value="neither">Neither
```

I have some text boxes on the form that I can use the same technique to find the value (
`var name = form.fname.value`
with a 
`<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">`
However, when I submit the form and build my post, the value for the radio buttons is always undefined. It works fine in Chrome, but nothing in IE or FireFox.

I tried `var env = document.getElementById('env').value`, but for some reason that always defaults to the first value (inside) no matter what I select. That method also does not return a value when using Chrome.

Is there something I'm missing for reading the checked value of a radio input in FF or IE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
function getValueFromRadioButton(name) {
   //Get all elements with the name
   var buttons = document.getElementsByName(name);
   for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      //Check if button is checked
      var button = buttons[i];
      if(button.checked) {
         //Return value
         return button.value;
      }
   }
   //No radio button is selected. 
   return null;
}
```

IDs are unique so you should not use the same ID for multiple items. You can remove the all the radio button IDs if you use this function.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same ID for multiple Elements, ID is unique for element on the page.

use different IDs.

edit: names can be the same. because then the radio buttons are as a group.

Comment: Names should be the same

Comment: yeah, my bad, got carried away.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the IDs should be different to be valid, but you could accomplish this by eliminating the IDs all together and using just the input name:

```
var form = document.forms['myForm'];
var radios = form.elements["env"];
var env = null;
for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++) {
    if(radios[i].checked == true) {
        env = radios[i].value;
    }
}

<form name="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="env" value="inside">Inside
<input type="radio" name="env" ivalue="outside" checked="checked">Outside
<input type="radio" name="env" value="both">Both
<input type="radio" name="env" value="neither">Neither
</form>
```

Comment: This should work but it just doesn't for me. In IE and FireFox, when I check the value of env, it is always undefined. I'm using this exact syntax too...

Comment: I was incorrect at first. The form.elements['env'] returns an array and you have to iterate over it to find which button is selected. This is similar to what I see @Afsa posted already, but different in that I'm using the form directly rather than querying the DOM for all buttons. This worked correctly in Firefox when changing the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Short & clear on ES-2015, for use with Babel:

```js
function getValueFromRadioButton( name ){
  return [...document.getElementsByName(name)]
         .reduce( (rez, btn) => (btn.checked ? btn.value : rez), null)
}

console.log( getValueFromRadioButton('payment') );
```

```html
<div>  
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="offline">
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="online">
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="part" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="free">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form#myForm');
var env_value = form.querySelector('[name="env"]:checked').value;
```