# How to get selected radio button's value in Microsoft edge?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I need to get the value of the selected radio button from a group of radio buttons, The below code works in chrome. I am able to use the value property on the input, however on Edge and IE, there is no value property on myRadio.

Is there a nice cross-browser alternative to get the selected radio button's value using plain javascript?

```js
function test(){
  //prints selected button's value on chrome while undefined on Edge
  console.log(document.getElementById("myForm").myRadio.value);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="0" />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2" />
</form>
<button onClick="test()">Test</button>
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387081/javascript-read-radio-button-value-in-ie-and-firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select the only one that has an attribute "checked":

```js
function test(){
  //prints selected button's value on chrome while undefined on Edge
  console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="myRadio"]:checked').value);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="0" />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2" />
</form>
<button onClick="test()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think queryselector should work fine in all browsers.

```js
function test(){
  //prints selected button's value on chrome while undefined on Edge
  console.log(document.querySelector('#myForm input[name="myRadio"]:checked').value);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="0" />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2" />
</form>
<button onClick="test()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Edge returns a HtmlCollection instead of RadioNodeList.

Result of document.getElementById("myForm").myRadio in:

EDGE

```
HtmlCollection length="3">
<input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="0"></input>
<input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="1"></input>
<input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="2"></input>
</HtmlCollection>
```

Chrome

```
RadioNodeList(3) [input, input, input, value: "1"]
0: input
1: input
2: input
length: 3
value: "1"
```

You could try and use the :checked

console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="myRadio"]:checked').value);

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the following methods:

Method 1: using document.querySelector() method:

```
    function test() {
        //prints selected button's value on chrome while undefined on Edge
        console.log(document.querySelector("input[name = 'myRadio']:checked").value);
    }
```

Method 2: Using document.getElementsByName() method to get the radio list, then check which radio is checked:

```
    function test() {
        //prints selected button's value on chrome while undefined on Edge

        var radioes = document.getElementsByName('myRadio');
        var selectedvalue;
        for (var i = 0; i < radioes.length; i++) {
            if (radioes[i].checked) {
                selectedvalue = radioes[i].value;
            }
        }
        console.log(selectedvalue);
    }
```

Method 3: Add JQuery reference, using JQuery selector to get the checked value:

JQuery reference:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript method:

```
    function test() {
        //prints selected button's value on chrome while undefined on Edge

        console.log($("input:radio[name='myRadio']:checked").val());
    }
```

Comment: could not understand method 3, why do you need jQuery here?

Comment: It's just a way to get the selected value, if you don't want to use this method, you can ignore it.